# What's the performance impact of disabling eager_load in production.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, eager-loading

My rails 4.1 app connects to a second, non-primary server via SSH for a backend jobs. Consequently, when the rails app restarts daily, the SSH connection needs to be live/up (rather the second, non-primary server needs to live/up), otherwise the the app crashes. This is due to eager loading by default being set to true in `production.rb` (`config.eager_load = true`).

I'm tempted to break this dependency by disabling eager loads, but I'm not able to find much information on the performance impact. So, my questions are...

1) if `eager_load` is set to `false`, will that simple slow down the app's startup time, or will the app eagerly load resources the first time they are hit?

3) If `eager_load` is simply turned off, to what degree will this impact the performance off the app (more subjective question)?

2) The model that performs the SSH connection are under folder `app\models\legacy`. Instead of changing `eager_load` to false, can that folder be excluded from eager loaded resources? If so, how? I believe I would need to edit `config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**/}')]` but not entirely sure.

**production.rb:**

```
  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true
```

Comment: Instead of changing the eager loading, could you not change the class so loading/parsing the class does not directly accesses ssh? Or make it more robust?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `eager_load=false` will probably *speed up* your app's startup, because loading will be deferred until necessary.

However, the penalty is that your app will likely use more memory (which is usually the most scarce server resource). I suspect that you may also run into threading bugs if you use a multithreaded server (e.g. puma) with `eager_load=false`.

Since Rails automatically includes all `app/*` directories in its eager load paths, I can't think of an easy way to exclude `app/models/legacy` while eager-loading everything else.

Instead, you could move the contents of `app/models/legacy` to e.g. `legacy/` at the root of your project and add that to the `autoload_paths`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/legacy )
```

Now Rails will still be able to find those files, but they won't be eagerly loaded in production.

Answer (score 2):

disable_dependency_loading Disables the automatic dependency loading if the config.eager_load is set to true.

for detailed info please have a look on this blog -
http://blog.arkency.com/2014/11/dont-forget-about-eager-load-when-extending-autoload/